# Invalid Viewstate

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, webforms

I always got this error guys on my site.Anybody got a solution.

```
Stacktrace
at System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptStringWithIV(String s, IVType ivType) at System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptString(String s) at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.DecryptParameter(NameValueCollection queryString) at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpResponse response, NameValueCollection queryString, VirtualFileReader fileReader) at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
Query String
d=J_c3w3Q59U-PnoRlWBPOJMVgHe_9Ile9wANEXiRFLzG8mequestManager._initialize('ctl00%24ScriptManager1'
```

I noticed that there are strings that got appended on the last part of ScriptResource.axd which are not part of the querystring(equestManager._initialize('ctl00%24ScriptManager1').I don't know how this string ends up here.I am using MS ajax, webforms and IIS7 on a shared hosting plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug caused by IE8 users, you can read about it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/27/Bugs-in-the-IE8-Lookahead-Downloader.aspx

The basics are that when IE8 processes the page, it sometimes just leaves 4kb out of it, and if your `<script src="ScriptResource.axd?....` started and gets truncated, when the page is rejoined with 4k missing, up until the matching quote to close the `src=""` is used, resulting in a very strange request to your server.

**Update:** [It's been fixed now with KB980182](http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2010/04/01/IE8-Lookahead-Downloader-Fixed.aspx) (4/1/2010)

Comment: @murak - Just wait for the errors to go away :) it's been fixed on the IE8 side just 2 days ago: http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2010/04/01/IE8-Lookahead-Downloader-Fixed.aspx